# Checking a check-box in one sheet tab will update another checkbox in a different sheet tab

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets

I have an inventory list in one tab with all the items including barcodes for every item. On the far right side of the sheet, I have code that when a checkbox is selected, the item row information is copied over to another tab which is our checkout page. The checkbox is included on this page, and it stays selected. I really want to be able to deselect the checkbox, which would delete the row from the checkout tab, and deselect the checkbox from the inventory tab. Is there a way to do this? At the very least, I would love to be able to deselect the checkbox on the checkout tab which would automatically deselect the same checkbox on the inventory tab, and then manually delete the row. Is any of this possible? here is my current code:

I have tried to find other posts, but anything that involves deselecting a box will create a new row at the bottom. This isn't what I want since my inventory list is in order from a barcode, and I don't want to create duplicates.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "Tech Lending" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Check-out");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast('Flag1');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Tech Lending" && e.range.columnStart==5 && e.value=="TRUE" && e.oldValue=="false") {
    //e.source.toast('Flag2');
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Check-out");
    var tnr=tsh.getLastRow()+1;
    var target=tsh.getRange(tnr, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1, sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(target);
    tsh.getRange(tnr,10).setValue(e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Check-out' && e.range.columnStart==5 && e.value=="FALSE" && e.oldValue=="true") {
    //e.source.toast('Flag3');
    e.source.getSheetByName('Tech Lending').getRange(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,10).getValue(),5).setValue("FALSE");
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

If I knew more about your data I could probably also uncheck the check on the Tech Lending page. Although I guess we could add a column with splice to the Check-out page that kept the row number of the Tech Lending Page.  We don't want to be doing a lookup inside of an onEdit() because as the Tech Lending page grows we may not be able to finish the script on time.

Comment: This is great! Thank you SO much. Here, I will add a screenshot of the inventory, but if it is impossible, I understand. I know I'm pushing Google sheets to the limit probably. Also, the bottom right screen says "flag1" when I hit the checkbox. Is this a concern I should have?

Comment: I'll comment those lines out I just use them for debugging.

Comment: If you ok with adding a column with the row number from the "Tech Lending" sheet then we can use that to reset the checkbox.

Comment: Ok, to give you a better idea of my data (I had to erase some emails), I made a copy of the two tabs! Here is the spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xm417evBs2ES9Hs9eE21QuNeF3TYQYxJ084GPRa3ROY/edit#gid=1324058920

Comment: I think that makes sense! Could you do it on that sheet I sent above, so i can understand exactly what you mean? I'm guessing you're talking about having to have a set data value to reset?

Comment: Can I use column J on the checkout sheet?

Comment: Absolutely! I should also mention that on we have to fill in the data from f-i once we click the checkmark from the previous tab. This seems to stop the curtain function from working properly/deleting the line.

Comment: Okay give this version a try.

Comment: You have to be careful not to check too fast because it takes a finite amount of time to complete the function.

Comment: That works incredibly well! Awesome, thank you so much